# String scanning in c

Tags: c, string

So here's a weird problem, when:

`if( x[j] == x[j++])` then the `scanf` function works fine, but if I change it into `if( x[j] == x[j + 1])` then `scanf` function for character array gets called infinite number of times.

It happened in two separate IDE ( but gcc compiler). How can two seemingly unrelated statements (a for loop and an if statement) affect each other ?

```
main( )
{
    char line[10][100], *x; 
    int i, j, sum;

    scanf("%d", &tc);
    for(i = 0; i < tc; i++)
    {
        scanf("%s", line[i]);
    }


    for( i = 0; i < tc; i++)
    {
        j = 0;
        sum = 0;
        x = line[i];

        while( x[j] != '\0' )
            if(x[j] == x[j+1])
                sum++;

        printf("%d\n", sum);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Where is `tc` declared?

Answer (score 4):

In this loop:

```
        while( x[j] != '\0' ) {
            if(x[j] == x[j+1]) {
                sum++;
            }
        }
```

you are not incrementing `j`, so it's an infinite loop, repeatedly testing the same two characters at `x[0]` and `x[1]`.

To fix this, change it to:

```
        while( x[j] != '\0' ) {
            if(x[j] == x[j+1]) {
                sum++;
            }
            j++; // <<< increment j on each iteration
        }
```

or make it more succinct with a `for` loop:

```
        for (j = 0; x[j] != '\0'; ++j) {
            if (x[j] == x[j+1]) {
                sum++;
            }
        }
```